# BC scale rounding error

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, bc

Trying to truncate the value of a `bc` calculation, however when I set the `scale=0` it returns 0 for the entire calculation. Setting `scale=1` returns a proper value of 357.3, but `scale=0` will always return 0.

Here is an example Calculation:

```
echo "scale=0; 3573 * (10 / 100)/1" | bc -l
0

echo "scale=1; 3573 * (10 / 100)/1" | bc -l
357.3
```

Is this not the proper way to truncate a floating point number to an integer using `bc`? I want to have it as an integer for bash scripting purposes.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by truncate?  You want to round to the nearest whole number?  Drop the decimal without rounding?

Comment: The "scale" variable applies to every calculation, not just the final result. (If this was not so, intermediate results would be of arbitrary precision.) So `(10 / 100)` goes to zero. `(3573 * 10) / 100` yields 357. I would probably set `scale = 12` and use `${val%.*}` in shell to truncate it, if you had to use large numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Other outputs where we play with the order of operations:

```bsh
echo "scale=0; 3573 * 10 / 100" | bc -l   # 357
echo "scale=0; 3573 / 100 * 10" | bc -l   # 350
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` seems much more straightforward,

```
awk 'BEGIN { print int(3573 * (10/100)/1) }'
357
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Paul_Pedant has the right idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638262/bc-scale-rounding-error#comment1195952_638262): `scale` applies to every part of the calculation. 10 / 100 = 0 at scale 0:

```
$ bc <<< 'scale = 0; 10 / 100'
0
```

So the whole calculation ends up being 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure why this works but if you store the equation in a variable first you can use scale 0:

```
echo "x = 3573 * (10 / 100); scale=0; x/1" | bc -l
```

Comment: It works because x is calculated with decimal numbers, and they are removed after scale is set to 0. Try `echo "x = 3573 * (10 / 100); x/1" | bc -l`, and `echo "scale = 0; x = 3573 * (10 / 100); x/1" | bc -l`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `printf`:

```bsh
$ LC_ALL=C printf "%.0f\n" $(echo "3573 * (10 / 100)/1" | bc -l)
357
```

Comment: The man bc page lies. It says the default scale is 0, but uses 20 digits for expressions -- unless you set the scale to 0.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant *- If bc is invoked with the -l option, a math library is preloaded and the default scale is set to 20. -* Under [Math library](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc).